# Difference Assigning an array in Function / Sub

Tags: excel, vba

When assigning the `CurrentRegion` to an array, the behaviour is different doing it in a function or in a sub.

```
Function WechselnDict(Text As String, Optional Gruppe As Byte)  
    Dim arr As Variant
    arr = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Value


End

Sub test()   
    Dim arr As Variant
    arr = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Value

End
```

In a sub (worked fine): the hole `CurrentRegion` is considered (e.g. `A1:D100`)

In a function only `A1` is assigend.

Why this difference? How can get the same range in the function? Please see my Screenshots. When I run the same code through a function (from the excel-GUI, from a Excel-cell-Formula) I dont get an array. But when I run the code through a sub, the array looks fine.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Maybe include the code for the sub and function?

Comment: And please include **how** you call/run the function. Reading [mcve] might help to improve your question.

Comment: @Eli3 in both cases `Debug.Print arr` would throw an error, because you cannot print an array with `Debug.Print` check the `CurrentRegion` directly using `Debug.Print ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Tabelle2").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Address`. It will give the same address (at least I cannot reproduce your issue). Make sure you specify in which workbook you are like using `ThisWorkbook`.

Comment: In the window "Überwachungsausdrücke" of the function you look at the wrong `arr` variable. Look at the blacked out "Kontext" and at "Wert" it says that this variable is out of context that means `arr` in that window is not the variable in the function but in another context. • You see the same effect in your other picture below where one `arr` variable is in context `fun_Minerg.WechselnDict` and it is out of context of the `test` sub. So please check again the `arr` of your function (mark the variable **in the function** with the cursor and drag it into the window "Überwachungsausdrücke").

Comment: Finally found the solution, actually it is not a solution. It just can not work, it is a special behaviour, maybe locked by security reasons. Read this: https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/currentregion-doesnt-work-when-function-referenced-in-worksheet-cell.694502/post-3441881