# Filter a 2D-Array and slice to 1D

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

Have an imported array with 3 columns:

[image: 2D-Array]

Goal is to filter by the 3rd column given by a Value (e.g. "1") and give back an 1D-Array to a UDF-Excel-Formula. Some issues with my code:

1.1) Is there a better way to shorten the code? Do many similar loops.

1.2) As there are many Formulas in the Excel-Sheet the Code will run many times. Can I avoid at least to UBounds to count the length of the origin-2D-Array (as they will remain always the same)?

2. The Code don't reach "fArray = arr1D". So It will not write nothing back. Can someone help? Thanks.

Part of my code, after have imported values from Excel-Range into a 2D-Array:

```
Function fArray(ArrName As String, Optional Gruppe As Byte)

Dim arr As Variant, arr1D as Variant
Dim i as long, j as Long, c as long

    'Count Matches
    For i = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
        If arr(i, 3) = Gruppe Then           'Filter
            c = c + 1
        End If
    Next i
    
    'If no Match exit
    If c = 0 Then
        Exit Function
    End If
    
    ReDim arr1D(1 To c, 1 To 1)         

    'Generate new filtered Array    
    For i = 1 To UBound(arr, 1)
        If arr(i, 1) > 1 Then
            j = j + 1
            arr1D(j, 1) = arr(i, 1)         'Assign and Slice from 2D to 1D
            
        End If
    Next i
    
    fArray = arr1D                          'Write back to Excel-Formula (UDF)
    
End Function
```

Comment: There's an `As` inside your second loop -  is that a method call?

Comment: Sorry, did fix, shouldn't be there

Comment: I doubt the call to UBound() is going to be a big performance hit, but you can reduce it to a single call if you store it in a variable first.  Loop counters are only evaluated once - when first entering the loop - so there's no repeated hit there.  FYI your return array is 2-D, same as the input array: the only difference is in the second dimension upper limit.

Comment: Your code is not returning the expected result because you are checking the first column if greater than 1 `If arr(i, 1) > 1 Then` instead of the third `If arr(i, 3) > 1 Then`. Also it is unclear what you want to return: the values from the first or thrid column i.e.`arr1D(j, 1) = arr(i, 1)` or `arr1D(j, 1) = arr(i, 3)` in a 2D or a 1D array i.e. `Redim arr1D(1 To c, 1 To 1)` or `Redim arr1D(1 To c)`.

Comment: @VBasic2008 Want to return only the values from the first column. If I change to `If arr(i, 3) > 1` and/or `Redim arr1D(1 To c)` then the Index in arr1D will be beyond the valid Range. This will result that arr1D will not be fill up. My code was in respect thereof correct, but the rest not.

Comment: It will work, if you use `arr1D(j) = arr(i, 1)`. One dimension (1D) means that you don't have `, 1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Array, Dictionary, ArrayList

- `TESTfArray` tests your function `fArray`.
- `fArray` shows how you could use the three following functions in your case.
- `vLookupArray`, `vLookupDictionary` and `vLookupArrayList` show three solutions to your case. They basically do the same thing. All solutions will return a 1D array. `vLookupArray` will return a one-based array, while the other two solutions will return zero-based arrays. Which is more efficient is up to you to find out.
- `TESTvLookup` will just test all three functions.

---

- Learn about the `Dictionary` object [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dictionary-object), [here](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-dictionary/) and [here](https://www.snb-vba.eu/VBA_Dictionary_en.html), and about the `ArrayList` [here](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-arraylist/) and [here](https://www.snb-vba.eu/VBA_Arraylist_en.html).

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub TESTfArray()
    Dim arr As Variant
    arr = fArray("NamedRangeName", 1)
    If Not IsEmpty(arr) Then
        Debug.Print Join(arr, vbLf)
    End If
End Sub

Function fArray(ArrName As String, Optional Gruppe As Byte) As Variant
    
    Dim arr As Variant
    
    ' Code to get 'arr' from ArrName.
    ' e.g.:
    arr = Range(ArrName).Value
    'arr = Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    
    If Not IsEmpty(arr) Then
        fArray = vLookupArray(arr, Gruppe, 3, 1)
        'fArray = vLookupDictionary(arr, Gruppe, 3, 1)
        'fArray = vLookupArrayList(arr, Gruppe, 3, 1)
    End If

End Function

Function vLookupArray(TwoD As Variant, _
    ByVal LookupValue As Variant, _
    ByVal LookupColumn As Long, _
    ByVal ReturnColumn As Long) _
As Variant
    Dim rCount As Long: rCount = UBound(TwoD, 1)
    Dim OneD As Variant: ReDim OneD(1 To rCount)
    Dim i As Long
    Dim n As Long
    For i = 1 To rCount
        If TwoD(i, LookupColumn) = LookupValue Then
            n = n + 1
            OneD(n) = TwoD(i, ReturnColumn)
        End If
    Next i
    If n > 0 Then
        ReDim Preserve OneD(1 To n)
        vLookupArray = OneD
        'Debug.Print "Array:" & vbLf & Join(vLookupArray, vbLf)
    End If
End Function

' Dictionary: Item, Count, Keys
Function vLookupDictionary(TwoD As Variant, _
    ByVal LookupValue As Variant, _
    ByVal LookupColumn As Long, _
    ByVal ReturnColumn As Long) _
As Variant
    With CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        Dim i As Long
        For i = 1 To UBound(TwoD, 1)
            If TwoD(i, LookupColumn) = LookupValue Then
                .Item(TwoD(i, ReturnColumn)) = Empty
            End If
        Next i
        If .Count > 0 Then
            vLookupDictionary = .Keys
           'Debug.Print "Dictionary:" & vbLf & Join(vLookupDictionary, vbLf)
        End If
    End With
End Function

' ArrayList: Add, Count, ToArray
Function vLookupArrayList(TwoD As Variant, _
    ByVal LookupValue As Variant, _
    ByVal LookupColumn As Long, _
    ByVal ReturnColumn As Long) _
As Variant
    With CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
        Dim i As Long
        For i = 1 To UBound(TwoD, 1)
            If TwoD(i, LookupColumn) = LookupValue Then
                .Add TwoD(i, ReturnColumn)
            End If
        Next i
        If .Count > 0 Then
            vLookupArrayList = .ToArray
            'Debug.Print "ArrayList:" & vbLf & Join(vLookupArrayList, vbLf)
        End If
    End With
End Function

Sub TESTvLookup()
    Dim cel As Range
    Set cel = Range("A2")
    Dim rng As Range
    With cel.CurrentRegion
        Set rng = cel.Resize( _
            .Rows.Count + .Row - cel.Row, _
            .Columns.Count + .Column - cel.Column)
    End With
    Debug.Print "Range Address:" & vbLf & rng.Address(0, 0)
    Dim TwoD As Variant
    TwoD = rng.Value
    Dim OneD As Variant
    OneD = vLookupArray(TwoD, 1, 3, 1)
    If Not IsEmpty(OneD) Then
        Debug.Print "Array:" & vbLf & Join(OneD, vbLf)
    End If
    OneD = vLookupDictionary(TwoD, 1, 3, 1)
    If Not IsEmpty(OneD) Then
        Debug.Print "Dictionary:" & vbLf & Join(OneD, vbLf)
    End If
    OneD = vLookupArrayList(TwoD, 1, 3, 1)
    If Not IsEmpty(OneD) Then
        Debug.Print "ArrayList:" & vbLf & Join(OneD, vbLf)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked fine! Dictionary was my favorite. For your info: This code can not work in a Function: `arr = Range("A1").CurrentRegion` . See here: [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65179281/difference-assigning-an-array-in-function-sub

Comment: Thanks for the `Current Region` tip, I had no idea. Be careful with the dictionary, it will return unique values from column 1 which are already unique in your case. In other cases you might not want this and you will have to use the other solutions. In other cases you might want unique values, when only the dictionary will work.